# Detect keyboard on mode when navigating in react-native

Tags: react-native

In the sign up process of my react-native application, I have to navigate from email screen to password screen etc. When I click NEXT from the email screen, when I go to the password screen, still the keyboard is on. How can I detect if the keyboard is on or off when Navigate to a new screen?

Once we are in the password screen, keyboard listeners are working properly. This is my code. Only issue is, I can't detect the keyboard status when the screen is loading.

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            email: {
                value: "",
                valid: false,
                touched: false,
                validationRules: {
                    isEmail: true
                }
            },
            headerStyles: {
                marginTop: 30,
                marginBottom: 70,
                marginLeft: 20
            },
            buttonTouched: false,
            emailAlreadyTaken: false
        }
    }

    // componentDidMount
    componentDidMount() {
        this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidShow", this._keyboardDidShow);
        this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidHide", this._keyboardDidHide);
    }

    // componentWillMount
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
        this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove(); 
    }

    // If the keyboard is visible
    _keyboardDidShow = () => {
        this.setState({
            headerStyles: {
                marginTop: 10,
                marginBottom: 30,
                marginLeft: 20
            } 
        });
    }

    // If the keyboard is not visible
    _keyboardDidHide = () => {
        this.setState({
            headerStyles: {
                marginTop: 30,
                marginBottom: 70,
                marginLeft: 20
            }
        });
    }

    // navigation options
    static navigationOptions = () => {
        return {
            headerTitle: null,
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: "white"
            }
        };
    };
```

How can I detect the keyboard status when I navigate to a new screen?

Answer (score 0):

```
// If the keyboard is visible
_keyboardDidShow = () => {
    this.setState({
        keyBoardIsOn: true, // SET TO FALSE KEYBOARD SHOWN
        headerStyles: {
            marginTop: 10,
            marginBottom: 30,
            marginLeft: 20
        } 
    });
}

// If the keyboard is not visible
_keyboardDidHide = () => {
    this.setState({
        keyBoardIsOn: false, // SET TO FALSE KEYBOARD HIDDEN
        headerStyles: {
            marginTop: 30,
            marginBottom: 70,
            marginLeft: 20
        }
    });
}

_navigate = () = {
    if(this.state.keyBoardIsOn) {
        // Do Stuff
    }
}
```